# Можно ли передавать многострочные лямбды как параметры методов в C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, lambda, делегаты

Всем привет. Есть основная форма, в ней DataGridView, хочу заполнять его числами в созданном мной потоке. Можно ли передать лямбду из нескольких операторов как параметр метода (в данном случае конструктора)? Знаю что можно объявить делегат до конструктора и передать переменную, содержащую ссылку на объект. По моему мнению так кажется красивее, но такой вариант неправильный.

```
private void SetData(object number)
{
    DataTable.Invoke(new Action<int>(n =>
    {
        DataTable.RowCount = n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            DataTable.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i.ToString();
            DataTable.Update();
        }
    };), (int)number);
}

private void StartButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(SetData);
    thread.Start(10000);
}
```

Comment: Что значит неправильный?

Comment: Он не компилируется студией, так писать нельзя (как в примере)

Comment: Я уже ответил...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точку с запятой убери и должно заработать. Хотя я бы ещё new Action выпилил.